# Getting problem in javascript file in my extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

i am still new here so mighty this will not proper but still consider it.
So i have created a extension which integrates with gmail browser and add buttons in gmail gui to write mail but
Problem is: when i click first time "use chatgpt" button (name of button that i added in gmail gui using extension) it will produce output perfectly but when i again click button second time to regenerate it will clear previous output but not provide newer one. Again on 3rd time it works and not on 4th time

Weird problem. below is my the javascript code of extension

```
// Use a MutationObserver to watch for changes to the Gmail page
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  // Check if the "send" button is visible
  var sendButton =
    document.querySelector('[data-tooltip="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬"]') ||
    document.querySelector('[data-tooltip="Enviar ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬"]');

  if (sendButton) {
    // The "send" button is visible, so add the new button next to it
    var sendButtonContainer = sendButton.parentNode.parentNode;
    var newButton = document.createElement("div");
    newButton.innerHTML =
      '<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3" style="user-select: none; margin: 5px;" data-tooltip="Use ChatGPT"><div class="aoq">Use ChatGPT</div></div>';
    sendButtonContainer.insertBefore(
      newButton,
      sendButtonContainer.nextSibling
    );

    // Add an event listener to the new button to handle clicks
    var scribeButton = document.querySelector('[data-tooltip="Use ChatGPT"]');
    if (scribeButton) {
      scribeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Get the text content of the Gmail compose window and the email conversation
        var composeWindow =
          document.querySelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf") ||
          document.querySelector(".editable.LW-avf");
        var conversation =
          document.querySelector(".ii.gt") ||
          document.querySelector(".ii.gt.adP.adO");

        var prompt = "";
        if (composeWindow && composeWindow.innerText) {
          // Add a heading before the email conversation
          prompt =
            "Consider the previous email exchange:\n" + conversation.innerText;

          // Insert the instructions after the previous conversation
          prompt +=
            "\n\nWrite a response email paraphrasing the following:\n" +
            composeWindow.innerText;

          // Clear the text content of the compose window
          composeWindow.innerText = "\n";
        }

        // Show a spinner while the request is being processed
        scribeButton.innerHTML =
          '<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3" style="user-select: none; margin: 5px;" data-tooltip="Use ChatGPT"><div class="aoq">Loading...</div></div>';

        // Send a message to the background script to get a response from ChatGPT
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
          { type: "generate-text", prompt: prompt },
          function (response) {
            // Check if the response is an error
            if (response.type === "error") {
              // Show an error message to the user
              scribeButton.innerHTML = '<div class="aoq">Error</div>';
            } else {
              // Insert the generated text into the Gmail compose window
              if (composeWindow && composeWindow.innerText) {
                // The compose window exists and has text content, so append the generated text to its text
                composeWindow.innerHTML += "<p>" + response.text + "</p>";

                // Append the message indicating that the email was generated by ChatGPT
                composeWindow.innerHTML +=
                  "<p>This email was entirely generated by ChatGPT.</p>";

                scribeButton.innerHTML =
                  '<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3" style="user-select: none; margin: 5px;" data-tooltip="Use ChatGPT"><div class="aoq">Use ChatGPT</div></div>';
              }
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }

    // Stop observing the page
    observer.disconnect();
  }
});

// Start observing the Gmail page
var target = document.querySelector("html");
observer.observe(target, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

i mighty think this issue is caused by event listener. i even try to make some changes with it.
correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.

Comment: Try debugging it in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm i have tried to find my file in chrome devtool but problem is my file is not there. mighty because i directly tried to directly manipulate gmail DOM

Comment: Apparently you look in the wrong place (there's a [separate panel for this](/a/60202310/)).